# How to add submenu of catalog?

Tags: magento-1.9

this is my `config.xml` file code. I want to add my module Matrid_FeedManager submenu in Catalog but its not working

```
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <catalog>               
            <children>
                <web module="web">
                    <title>Matrid_FeedManager</title>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>               
                    <children>
                        <items module="web">
                            <title>Manage Items</title>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <action>web/adminhtml_web</action>
                        </items>
                    </children>
                </web>
            </children>     
        </catalog>
    </menu>
    <acl>
```

Comment: please add full code of your config.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create adminhtml.xml file and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog>
            <children>
                <pquestion>
                    <title>Product Question</title>
                    <sort_order>500</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <pquestion>
                            <title>Questions</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/pquestion</action>
                        </pquestion>
                        <pquestion1>
                            <title>Settings</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/pquestion</action>
                        </pquestion1>
                    </children>
                </pquestion>
            </children>
        </catalog>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <title>Setting</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

That **menu** part in your config.xml looks fine, so your problem could be in **acl** section of the file, or maybe your module **web** is not well defined

Comment: i had done it actually it was minor mistake.. can u tell me i want to call template on my custom module  with grid??

Comment: I think you'd accept a valid answer for this question (maybe you can post your own solution) & open a new one for that